# NSView Border Color

Tags: cocoa

i am applying a border to NSView but how can i change the bordercolor. Using NSColor with setBorderColor is showing a warning. I want to use Orange Color in Border

```
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    self .layer.masksToBounds   = YES;    
    self.layer.borderWidth      = 6.0f ;

    [self.layer setBorderColor:CGColorGetConstantColor(kCGColorBlack)];
```

How can i set other colors(excluding black and white) in Border

Regards,
Haseena

Comment: There is a category for AppKit that does a conversion from `NSColor` to `CGColor` here: https://gist.github.com/707921. It might worth a look.

Comment: You need to use `NSBox`, which is a subclass of `NSView`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert to a CGColorRef

```
NSColor *orangeColor = [NSColor orangeColor];

// Convert to CGColorRef
NSInteger numberOfComponents = [orangeColor numberOfComponents];
CGFloat components[numberOfComponents];
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = [[orangeColor colorSpace] CGColorSpace];    
[orangeColor getComponents:(CGFloat *)&components];    
CGColorRef orangeCGColor = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, components);

// Set border
self.view.layer.borderColor = orangeCGColor;

// Clean up
CGColorRelease(orangeCGColor);
```

Or if you can require 10.8+, use [`[aColor CGColor]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSColor/CGColor)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `NSBox`, which is a subclass of `NSView` and designed to handle these cases

```
let box = NSBox()
box.boxType = .custom
box.alphaValue = 1
box.borderColor = NSColor.red
box.borderType = .lineBorder
box.borderWidth = 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Wow... so simple these days. In your NSView when created:

```
self.wantsLayer = YES;
self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```

Then in `drawRect` (so that you can respond to changes for dark mode or other Appearances) set the border color.... and DON'T Forget to use system colors that respond to Appearance changes or colors you define in Asset catalog that support all appearances you support.

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    self.layer.borderColor = [NSColor systemGrayColor];
    // or color defined in Asset Catalog
    self.layer.borderColor = [NSColor colorNamed:@"BorderColor"].CGColor;
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

It's that simple.